# Two inequalities with inclusion-exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, integer-lattices

Let $S$ be a base set of size $n$.
Also denote $k$ of $S$'s subsets by $A_1,...,A_k\in 2^S$ such that $\bigcup_i A_i=S$.
Furthermore, let $n_\alpha=\lvert\bigcap_{i\in\alpha}A_i\rvert$ be the size of the intersection of sets in the index set $\alpha\subset I=\{1,...,k\}$.
For example, $n_{1,3,4}=\lvert A_1\cap A_3\cap A_4\rvert$ if $k\ge4$.

We know that $\forall i\in I: n_i\ge3$ and $\sum_i n_i>\sum_{\alpha\subset I} (-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert+1}{n_\alpha\choose2}$.

If I could show that $\sum_{\alpha\subset I} (-1)^{\lvert\alpha\rvert+1}n_\alpha\le2k$, that would help me a lot with my project.

I have tried an inductive proof but got stuck.
I have also tried to represent the task with two lattices (or semi-lattices, I am not sure) and find some mapping there but that failed too.
I have checked Richard Stanley's book on Enumerative Combinatorics but I did not see anything that would connect inclusion-exclusion sums of numbers and binomial coefficients.

I would be very grateful for any ideas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will adopt the convention that the empty intersection $\bigcap_{i\in\varnothing} A_i$ is $S$ (which is natural because $S$ is the identity of the intersection operator on the algebra of sets over $S$.) Also, we will use the [indicator function notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

$$ \mathbf{1}_A (x) = \begin{cases}
1, & x \in A, \\
0, & x \notin A.
\end{cases} $$

This is convenient, because for each $\alpha \subseteq I$ we have

$$ n_{\alpha}
= \left| \bigcap_{i \in \alpha} A_i \right|
= \sum_{x\in S} \mathbf{1}_{\bigcap_{i \in \alpha} A_i}(x)
= \sum_{x\in S} \prod_{i\in\alpha} \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x). $$

Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\alpha \subseteq I} (-1)^{|\alpha|+1} n_{\alpha}
&= \sum_{\alpha \subseteq I} (-1)^{|\alpha|+1} \sum_{x\in S} \prod_{i\in\alpha} \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x) \\
&= - \sum_{x\in S} \sum_{\alpha \subseteq I} \prod_{i\in\alpha} \bigl(-\mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x) \bigr) \\
&= - \sum_{x\in S} \prod_{i\in I} \bigl(1-\mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x) \bigr) \\
&= - \sum_{x\in S} \prod_{i\in I} \mathbf{1}_{S \setminus A_i}(x) \\
&= - \sum_{x\in S} \mathbf{1}_{S \setminus \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i}(x) \\
&= - \left| S \setminus {\textstyle \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i} \right|.
\end{align*}

Note that this formula is valid for *any* finite family of subsets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $S$. Now, OP's condition tells that $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i = S$. Therefore, we always have

$$ \sum_{\alpha \subseteq I} (-1)^{|\alpha|+1} n_{\alpha} = 0 $$

regardless of all the other conditions imposed.

> **Example.** Consider $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and
> \begin{align*}
> A_1 &= \{2, 4, 6\}, &
> A_2 &= \{2, 3, 5, 6\}, \\
> A_3 &= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, &
> A_4 &= \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.
> \end{align*}
> Clearly, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{4} A_i = S$. Also,
> \begin{align*}
> n_{\varnothing} &= |\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}| = 6, &
> n_{\{1\}} &= |\{2, 4, 6\}| = 3, \\
> n_{\{2\}} &= |\{2, 3, 5, 6\}| = 4, &
> n_{\{3\}} &= |\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}| = 5, \\
> n_{\{4\}} &= |\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}| = 5, &
> n_{\{1, 2\}} &= |\{2, 6\}| = 2, \\
> n_{\{1, 3\}} &= |\{2, 4\}| = 2, &
> n_{\{1, 4\}} &= |\{2, 4, 6\}| = 3, \\
> n_{\{2, 3\}} &= |\{2, 3, 5\}| = 3, &
> n_{\{2, 4\}} &= |\{2, 3, 5, 6\}| = 4, \\
> n_{\{3, 4\}} &= |\{2, 3, 4, 5\}| = 4, &
> n_{\{1, 2, 3\}} &= |\{2\}| = 1, \\
> n_{\{1, 2, 4\}} &= |\{2, 6\}| = 2, &
> n_{\{1, 3, 4\}} &= |\{2, 4\}| = 2, \\
> n_{\{2, 3, 4\}} &= |\{2, 3, 5\}| = 3, &
> n_{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}} &= |\{2\}| = 1.
> \end{align*}
> (We can also check that $\{A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4\}$ satisfies all the other conditions imposed by OP. However, they are not relevant to the computation below.) So,
> \begin{align*}
> &\sum_{\alpha \subseteq I} (-1)^{|\alpha|+1} n_{\alpha} \\
> &= (-1)^{0+1} \cdot 6 + (-1)^{1+1} \cdot 3 + (-1)^{1+1} \cdot 4 + (-1)^{1+1} \cdot 5 + (-1)^{1+1} \cdot 5 \\
> &\quad + (-1)^{2+1} \cdot 2 + (-1)^{2+1} \cdot 2 + (-1)^{2+1} \cdot 3 + (-1)^{2+1} \cdot 3 + (-1)^{2+1} \cdot 4 + (-1)^{2+1} \cdot 4 \\
> &\quad + (-1)^{3+1} \cdot 1 + (-1)^{3+1} \cdot 2 + (-1)^{3+1} \cdot 2 + (-1)^{3+1} \cdot 3 + (-1)^{4+1} \cdot 1 \\
> &= 0.
> \end{align*}

Comment: I am back and thank you! This is unexpected, I will have to digest this and then come back to the forum soon.

Comment: @drumath, In fact, the computation I made and the result thereof is really about the usual inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Yes I see that. My original problem is in a different format. I have two different representations of an object as two different bipartite graphs, one of them gives a necessary and the other a sufficient condition for a property via vertex covers. I was trying to prove a connection between the two representations to improve my intuition. This is too easy and therefore not good. I wonder what I did wrong.

Comment: Anyway, your answer is helpful and thank you for that.

Comment: I already accepted but would it be less obvious if I added that $\lvert\alpha\rvert > 0$ for all sums? I.e. the entire set $S$ is never included.

Comment: nah, trivial answer. never mind. I will need more time to figure out what I need here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For $r=0,1,\dots,k$ let $U_{r}$ denote the set of elements that have exactly $r$ occurrences in the $A_{i}$; so actually: $$x\in U_r\iff\sum_{i=1}^k1_{A_i}(x)=r$$
Then:

$$1_{U_{r}}=\sum_{\alpha\subseteq I}\binom{\left|\alpha\right|}{r}\left(-1\right)^{\left|\alpha\right|-r}1_{\bigcap_{i\in\alpha}A_{i}}\tag1$$

and consequently: $$\left|U_{r}\right|=\sum_{\alpha\subseteq I}\binom{\left|\alpha\right|}{r}\left(-1\right)^{\left|\alpha\right|-r}n_{\alpha}\tag2$$
This under the convention that a binomial coefficient $\binom{m}s$ takes value $0$ if $s\notin\{0,\dots,m\}$.

In your case we have $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i$ so that every element has an occurrence
in at least one of the $A_{i}$.

That means that $U_{0}=\varnothing$ and consequently:

$$0=\left|U_{0}\right|=\sum_{\alpha\subseteq I}\binom{\left|\alpha\right|}{0}\left(-1\right)^{\left|\alpha\right|}n_{\alpha}=\sum_{\alpha\subseteq I}\left(-1\right)^{\left|\alpha\right|}n_{\alpha}$$

---

If you are interested in a proof of $(1)$ then please let me know.

Comment: Thank you @drhab for your contribution. Unfortunately, I cannot accept two replies as answers. Also unfortunately, I was sloppy in formulating my question here and I'd like to bring my updated question to you attention: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4488680/427103

Comment: I don't think I can help you. The expressions $\binom{n_{\alpha}}2$ in your question are not recognizable for me. If it concerns PIE then I would rather expect expressions like $\binom{|\alpha|}2$ (or more generally as in my answer $\binom{|\alpha|}r$).